# How often does the Legion invade a zone?

Tags: world-of-warcraft

Is there a repeating pattern to when there is a Legion Invasion in the zones in the Broken Isles?  They seem to happen at completely random times, so it's hard to plan around when the next one will happen.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Reportedly there's an invasion every 18.5 hours - done by Blizzard so that everyone will be able to experience one regardless of when they work.

There's a [website](https://wow.gameinfo.io/invasions) you can use to check when the next one will be up.